# Order of addSubview messages affects buttons responding to the UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uikit

I have two views, one of them contains a button:

```
UIView *view1, *view2;
UIButton *button;
[view1 addSubview:button];
```

They are both on top of the parent view, view2 on top (with a bigger zPosition value):

```
UIView *parentView;
view1.layer.zPosition = 10;
view2.layer.zPosition = 0;
[parentView addSubview:view1];
[parentView addSubview:view2];
```

Only when I add subviews in this order (view1 first, view2 second), my button (inside view1) doesn't respond to the UIControlEventTouchUpInside event.
When I reversed the order, everything worked:

```
[parentView addSubview:view2];
[parentView addSubview:view1];
```

Although the UIControlEventTouchUpInside event didn't work, visually everything was okay even in the first case (view1 was shown on top of the view2). The order of addSubview messaged only affected the UIControlEventTouchUpInside event.

**Added**:
My question is: why does only one of the described ways work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right way is the second one

```
[parentView addSubview:view2];
[parentView addSubview:view1];
```

Or

```
[parentView addSubview:view2];
[view2 addSubview:view1];
```

but, by doing this:

```
view1.layer.zPosition = 10;
view2.layer.zPosition = 0;
```

You have only modified the "visual Layer", in this way view1 will remains below view2

Comment: Can I put view1 about view2 after it has already added to the parent view second?

Comment: sure, you can.. but it will be removed from parent and added to the other view